# How to enable a disabled app

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I recently disabled a default app (Google+, using `Settings -> Apps -> Google+ -> Disable`) on my phone. Is there a way to enable it again?

Answer (score 4):

The same way.

`Settings | Apps | (app) | Enable`

Disabled apps automatically sort to the **bottom** of the app list.