# How to enable a disabled app in Samsung

Tags: applications, disable-app

Phone: Samsung Galaxy S9, Android 10, OneUI2.0

After updating my OS last month, the "Enable" button disappears from App info panel(Settings | Apps | (app) | Enable, said [How to enable a disabled app](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18382/how-to-enable-a-disabled-app)). and "auto disable unused app" setting is not available, too.

If the app is installed by play store, I can re-enable it in play store app. If not, how to enable?

And I tried `pm enable ...` cmd in adb, but got

```
Security exception: Shell cannot change component state for .../null to 1
```